# Can I upgrade from Lion to Mavericks? Or must I upgrade to Mountain Lion, first?

Tags: upgrade, macos

I never bothered to upgrade my 2012 MacBook Air to Mountain Lion. Currently I am on Lion.

Can I upgrade straight to Mavericks, or do I need to first upgrade to Mountain Lion and then to Mavericks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Mavericks How To Upgrade](http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/) page you can update from Snow Leopard (10.6.8) Lion (10.7), or Mountain Lion(10.8) later to Mavericks (10.9) if your hardware meets the requirements, which yours does. I upgraded my 2012 MacBook Air to Mavericks about two weeks ago and the battery life is noticeably better.