# standalone upgrade from older version to current version osx

Tags: macos, upgrade, mac-appstore, software-update

I want a standalone upgrade from an older osx (10.7.4) to the current mavericks.

There is the free upgrade in the app store which normally would be perfect -- but my internet connection at home is slow and spotty.  The upgrade is 5GB in the store.  I get about 1GB, and my connection drops, and now I have to start over.

So what I want to do is get a standalone way of doing the upgrade -- this would allow me to use my other computer (faster connection) and sneakernet (use a USB stick) to transfer the file(s) to the Mac.

The combo and delta standalone updates you can get only apply within the same version.

Does anyone know of a way to do this standalone upgrade, even if I would have to apply multiple installs / updates / upgrades?

I suppose other solutions could include a multiple smaller file solution, or give the ability to resume the download from where it left off.

Comment: Please edit your question as this is very vague what you're exactly asking..

Comment: you should get the combo version. In cases where personal Internet connection is to slow or not reliable it is worth driving to Apple Store or Best buy, to get it there.

Comment: rob: Not to be combative, but your comment is about as vague as they come for constructive feedback.  Anything in particular that confuses you?

Comment: Thanks buscar, but the combo version is *within* the version; it just doesn't have to be the latest version.  I have an older version.  And I'm trying to avoid paying or traveling -- but that may be the only thing left..

Comment: Please try to focus on the problem you want to solve and on specific steps you have tried and which didn't work. At the moment it's a bit hard to separate between the problem and ideas you have to solve it. It might also be worth to have a look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, from how I read your question, it is already answered [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106047/can-i-upgrade-from-lion-to-mavericks-or-must-i-upgrade-to-mountain-lion-first/106048#106048)

Comment: patrix Please reread the question.  Its been edited, but the essentials are still there -- I cannot complete the 5GB download required to run the upgrade from the app store.

Comment: Why does the solution mentioned above (visit a store with good connectivity) not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the installer from wherever you have a decent connection, and then create a USB key with the installer.

Once you have downloaded the installer on any machine, see the [quick instructions here](http://bahut.alma.ch/2012/06/usb-osx-lion-installer-for-impatient.html#mavericks):

> Create a single GPT (GUID) partition on the USB key, and format it.
>   Then run:
>
> ```
> sudo "/Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia" --volume /Volumes/untitled --applicationpath "/Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app" --nointeraction
> ```
>
> "/Volumes/untitled" is the mount point of your USB key. For the
>   verbose version with pictures, [see here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/23/create-os-x-mavericks-install-drive/).